# Numbers formatting in C#

Tags: c#, formatting, numbers

I have numbers like this: 
-1.0001
-10000.01

And I need to get this: 
-1.0001
-10000,01

Requirements:
- Decimal separator is ","
- Group separator is " "
- part of a number after the comma can have different length, that depends from actual data.

I tried to use this mask: "### ### ##0.####" to format numbers.
When number is big - all is ok, but when it is small - I get spaces from the left of a number. I get this:
"-  1,0001"
"- 10 000,01"

As I understand these spaces are from the mask I used.

There are some workaround ways but they are not so beautiful and aesthetically wright.

Is there any way to do this correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're trying to do. What is the "." meant to be in your desired output, if you're using comma as the decimal separator and space as the group separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the NumberFormatInfo class to format your number. I used the code below to check my answer and it worked for the large/small cases I tested with:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double smallNumber = -1.01;
        double smallNumberMoreDigits = -1.0001;
        double bigNumber = -100000.001;
        double longNumber = 2.2347894612789;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru", false);            

        Console.Out.WriteLine(smallNumber.ToString("#,0.####"));
        Console.Out.WriteLine(smallNumberMoreDigits.ToString("#,0.####"));
        Console.Out.WriteLine(bigNumber.ToString("#,0.####"));
        Console.Out.WriteLine(longNumber.ToString("#,0.####"));

        Console.Read();
    }
```

EDIT:
A quick bit of detective work (I looked at your profile) tells me you're in Russia. Are you looking for the General Russian number formatting? I've changed the code above. Take a look and see if it fits your requirements. It gives me the following results:

-1,01
-1,0001
-100000,001

SECOND EDIT:
Added masking to get a better result on decimal places.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried NumberFormatInfo, but it didn't work because I forgot to set it's NumberDecimalDigits property.

Comment: I missed something. If for example the smallNumber variable = -1.01 I get -1,0100. It's not what expected. Expected -1,01.

Comment: I think that all is so because NumberFormatInfo works just like smallNumber.Format("N4");

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative approach. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: There are some problems with long numbers (for ex. 2.2347894612789 ) when I use "G" modifier. They are rounded in dependence of number's type and numbers are too long sometimes. I mean I can't set trailing part length to particular length. I can only set the length of a whole number. It's uncomfortable. This way is not flexible enough. But it gives the result.

Comment: You're right- you will need masking, but I think you will need both. Please see my updated code above.

Comment: The last solution worked perfectly. My mask was wrong. Yes, I use NumberFormatInfo. But I don't set it as my thread's current culture, I just use it's default formatting settings.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces were automatically removed by stackoverflow when you posted but I think you can solve your problem by just using Trim like

```
something.ToString("### ### ##0.####").Trim();
```

Comment: It helps if numbers are positive. When they're negative it won't work.

Comment: There is a workaround way to format the input number. If it's negative - make it positive, then apply the mask with Trim() and then add minus sign to the beginning. It works well, but seems odd to me.